# Update multiple fields in flask update route

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I have a small app made with flask.  I'm trying to make my update route code dryer.  So I have around 10 fields a user can choose to update in his/her own post.  Could someone please nudge me in the right direction, I know it should easy enough to solve but having one of those days.  So instead of having 10 lines I want to create a small function to do the work.  Current code looks like this..

```
@app.route("/post/<int:post_id>/update", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def update_post(post_id):
    post = Post.query.get_or_404(post_id)
    if post.author != current_user:
        abort(403)
    form = PostForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.picture.data:
            picture_file = save_recpic(form.picture.data)
            post.recipe_img = picture_file
        post.title = form.title.data
        post.description = form.description.data
        post.howto = form.howto.data
        post.ethnicity = form.ethnicity.data
        post.course = form.course.data
        post.vegetarian = form.vegetarian.data
        post.vegan = form.vegan.data
        post.nuts = form.nuts.data
        post.shellfish = form.shellfish.data
        post.meat = form.meat.data
        post.cook_time = form.cook_time.data
        for i in range (len(post.ingredients)):
            post.ingredients[i].name = form.ingredient[i].data
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your recipe has been updated!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('post', post_id=post.id))
```

So instead of having around 10 of the above I'm trying to make a function along the lines of..

```
def update_fields(form, post):
    fields = ['title', 'description', 'howto']
    for item in fields:
        form.item.data = post.item
    return form.item.data
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is going to be updated? Database record? From where do you call this function? Is only 1 field going to be updated or can all fields be updated all together at once? I am not sure what you are trying to do with the for loop and the return statement, but please elaborate in your question.

Comment: A database Post record will be updated.  I have a helpers.py file which I import functions from.  All fields will update at once.  I included the route above to make it clearer.  All I am trying to do is make my code dryer, thats why i'm trying to make a function to achieve this, thanks for looking.